# Same root folder for multiple website different robots.txt

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have a first website with this configuration:

```
server {
        server_name mywebsite.com;

        root /var/www/website/prod;
...
}
```

and a second one like this with the same root folder:

```
server {
        server_name pro.mywebsite.com;

        root /var/www/website/prod;
...
}
```

And the only problem is they have the same robots.txt file.

Is it possible to tell the second server to link the file robots.txt to another file like robots-pro.txt?

And by the way the url `http://pro.mywebsite.com/robots.txt` would open the file robots-pro.txt.

Comment: Try: `location = /robots.txt { try_files /robots-pro.txt =404; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the main domain I did to block robots-denyall.txt:

```
location /robots-denyall.txt {
        return 404;
}
```

And for the subdomain which I don't want to be referenced:

```
location = /robots.txt {
        alias /var/www/mywebsite/prod/robots-denyall.txt;
}
```